# Android - Can't make a directory

Tags: android, file, permissions, directory, storage

Here is my code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "newDir");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    System.out.println(dir.mkdirs());
}
```

It always prints false.

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have also tried the following variations of the first line of the code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "newDir");

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newDir");

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newDir/");

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "newDir");

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "newDir");

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/newDir");
```

Nothing works.

EDIT: Device OS version is 6.0.1 (a Nexus 9 tablet).

Comment: Please mention the device OS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to changed permission model since Android M.
You need to ask for the permission programmatically even though you've declared it in Manifest file.

Checkout my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163751/android-marshmallow-6-0-1-bluetooth-scan-returning-no-results/36164455#36164455)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856432/asking-for-permissions-while-using-locationmanager/35857017#35857017) for more details.